# Capistrano and ActiveMerchant Paypal will not Deploy due to ArgumentError: An API Certificate or API Signature is required to make requests to PayPal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, activemerchant

I have an eCommerce site that I use paypal via ActiveMechant. In Development everything works well, but when I deploy it gives me this error...

```
ArgumentError: An API Certificate or API Signature is required to make requests to PayPal
/var/www/ross_store/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activemerchant-1.48.0/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/paypal/paypal_common_api.rb:78:in `initialize'
```

My production.rb config looks like...

```
config.after_initialize do
ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :production
paypal_options = {
:login => ENV["PAYPAL_USER"],
:password => ENV["PAYPAL_PASS"],
:signature => ENV["PAYPAL_SIGNATURE"]
}
    ::EXPRESS_GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway.new(paypal_options)
end
```

All the ENV vars are available on the Host machine.

Similar to [API Signature is required to make requests to PayPal error, I have an API signature set already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082805/api-signature-is-required-to-make-requests-to-paypal-error-i-have-an-api-signat) but not on Heroku.

Anyone any Ideas?

Many Thanks in advance.

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, Im sure this is not a good way to do it but I moved the ActiveMerchant initilizer into its own Module and out of the production.rb and all seems well. If anyone knows any good reasons why this is a *bad* idea, please do let me know, but for now its working!

Cheers